# Global DLL Triger

Tags: sql, dll, triggers

I need block acess to SQL server only for some apps.
Our CRM have by desing at all users set db_owner schema.

I found this triger how block acess for one app. But I need add one more.

Can you help me?

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE TABLE master..PokusOLogin3
(
ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, Datum datetime DEFAULT GETDATE()
, LoginName SYSNAME
, Program SYSNAME
, Pocitac SYSNAME
)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [OnlyAppka]
ON ALL SERVER WITH EXECUTE AS 'sa'
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @LoginName SYSNAME
DECLARE @Pocitac SYSNAME

DECLARE @data XML
SET @data = EVENTDATA()

DECLARE @AppName SYSNAME
SELECT @AppName = program_name, @Pocitac = host_name FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions WHERE session_id = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SPID)[1]', 'int')

IF @AppName NOT LIKE 'Appka%'
       --Pokud spousteny program neni Appka
       SET @LoginName = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'SYSNAME')

       IF @LoginName NOT IN (SELECT p.name FROM sys.server_principals p JOIN sys.syslogins s ON p.sid = s.sid WHERE s.sysadmin = 1
                                                            UNION ALL SELECT service_account FROM sys.dm_server_services)
       --A pokud program nespousti administrator sql serveru, nebo sluzba sql serveru
             BEGIN
             ROLLBACK
             --Ukonci session (pokus o prihlaseni)
             INSERT INTO master..PokusOLogin (LoginName, Program, Pocitac)
             SELECT @LoginName --@LoginName
                    , @AppName, @Pocitac
             --A tento pokus zaloguj do tabulky
             END

END
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and specify what issues you are facing exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF @AppName NOT LIKE 'Appka%' OR @AppName NOT LIKE 'Appka1%'

Comment: Is not OR .. its AND :)

Comment: Imma sorry, but it s just operator, I am happy it helped :)